# Difficulty reading Multiple Tweet JSON file in python(attaching the link of the file)

Tags: python, json

[Please download the file from the given link, the link contain the json file which I am unable to read](https://github.com/abhianlytic/Python-Twitter-json-file/blob/master/python.json)

I tried the below code but it is not working:

```
import json

with open('G:/analytics/ISB CBA/Residency/Residency1&2/B9MPRACT/data/python.json','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        print("hello")
```

I know many solution and problems are there in StackOverflow but I have not found any solution to the problem I m facing while reading this json file.
Any response would be appreciable.

Comment: Don't iterate through each line of the file, as you will overwrite `tweet` each time. You should be able to open it as you are (using `with open("path/to/file", "r") as f`), and then use `tweets = json.loads(f)`. `tweets` will then be a Python dictionary, so you can find key:value pairs in it as you would normally with a dictionary.

Comment: @ResetACK thanks, but it is giving an error at my end as "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'TextIOWrapper" . could it be possible for you to read the same file which I have uploaded at the given GitHub location then that would be a great support to my ongoing project.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific - what error?

Comment: "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'TextIOWrapper"   getting this error

Comment: Ah my bad - `json.loads` is for loading from a string. In this case, since you're loading it from a file, you want to use `json.load` (no `s`)

Comment: However, in future, it pays dividends to simply google search the error you're getting (just copy/paste the error into the search bar). In this case it would have led you straight to the answer.

Comment: thanks but Now I am getting different error - "JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 2373)"

Comment: Refer to my previous comment

Answer (score -1):

Check if this works: 
pip install simplejson

import simplejson as json
with open('E:/Studies/ISB/python.json','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        print tweet

Comment: Why install a separate JSON library when python has one already included, that works perfectly fine?

Comment: That code works fine in python2 but not in python3. I need a solution in python3

Comment: @ResetACK Checking if simplejson helps since nothing else is working in python3. All of the above work in Python 2.7, in any case.